# How can I view the request body in ASP.NET Web API from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

How can I view the request body in ASP.NET Web API from Visual Studio? In ASP.NET MVC, you can use QuickWatch to inspect the `Request` object and view the content of the body and any posted form data. From what I read, ASP.NET Web API doesn't allow you to read the body more than once.

This is very annoying to deal with when trying to figure out why a specific value wasn't bound correctly. Is there a quick way to do this without setting up tracing/logging?

Comment: Firebug won't help you to accomplish what you want? It's watching the actual HTTP traffic from the browser, which VS can't really do.

Comment: The API request is coming from an external source I don't have access to.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The easiest it to install [`Fiddler`](http://fiddler2.com/). Then you will see everything that gets sent over the wire and inspect not only the request payload but the HTTP headers as well. And if you are consuming the API from javascript, things like FireBug, Chrome Developer Toolbar and IE Developer Tools will show you all network requests made by the website.

If you absolutely must inspect the traffic on the server then if you are hosting your Web API inside an ASP.NET application you could put the following line in your immediate window:

```
new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd()
```

Comment: or you could also do `request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` too. This would buffer the request content and the rest of the pipeline would still work as expected,but if you use StreamReader to read the stream to the end, you would need to make sure to reset the position so that rest of the pipeline works. However, as you mentioned `Fiddler` would be my first choice.

Comment: ASP.NET Core: ```new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.Body).ReadToEnd()``` and to reset the read position, ```Request.Body.Position = 0```

Answer (score 4):

**if you need body >> Form-data**

> Post       localhost:53356/api/carparksapi/GetRecod
>
> key=jsonRequest    and   value=[{"abcd":"zxxx"}]

```
       //  API -Controller Method :: 

        var httpContext = (HttpContextWrapper)Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"];
        var foo = httpContext.Request.Form["jsonRequest"];
        return foo; //This is value passed in request
```

Answer (score 3):

For ASP.NET Core use this in the immediate window:

```
new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.Body).ReadToEnd()
```

Comment: Remeber to set the `Request.Body.Position=0` after reading so your code can read it again!

Answer (score 2):

For me @DarinDimitrov answer gave

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'StreamReader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Adding namespace did it

`new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd()`

Hope this saves you some time

Answer (score 2):

For me @Matas Vaitkevicius answer gave

> error CS1061: 'HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for
>   'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'HttpContextBase' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Replacing HttpContext.Current with System.Web.HttpContext.Current did it for me

```
new System.IO.StreamReader(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd()
```

Hope this saves you some time

Answer (score 1):

Any of these answers could work if the position of the steam is at position 0.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position =  0;
var body = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```